# Bokeh, can't use callback with CSV files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, bokeh

I have been trying to do this for the most of the night, it really shouldn't be this difficult. But with all the different releases and buggy examples out there I am finding it difficult. Can someone put me straight?

I just need to get my foot in the door by updating a plot when I update a CSV file.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd


p  = figure()

f = open('lines.csv', 'r')
cv = pd.read_csv(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(cv)
f.close()

X  = df.x
Y  = df.y
r1 = p.line(X,Y, line_width=2)
session = push_session(curdoc())
ds = r1.data_source

def update():
    f = open('lines.csv', 'r') 
    cv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cv)

    ds.data['X'] = df.x
    ds.data['Y'] = df.y
    f.close()


curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)
session.show()
session.loop_until_closed()
```

It plots the graph, but no updating when I change the CSV. Thanks.

Comment: can simplify first lines to `df = pd.read_csv('lines.csv')`

Comment: @elsherbini Yeah, I was just making sure that it wasn't an IO thing, I assumed pandas used a context manager, but when you can't get things to work you'll try anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues I found:

First, you don't need to include the `session` management stuff. It's primarily for doing things like exchanging components (plots, layouts, etc) with others, while you're just updating data.

Second, in your `update` callback you're setting uppercase "X" and "Y", while I think they're stored as lowercase "x" and "y". That's because doing
`r1 = p.line(x=X,y=Y, line_width=2)`. So you're setting values that aren't used in the plot.

Working code is:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd

p  = figure()

f = open('lines.csv', 'r')
cv = pd.read_csv(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(cv)
f.close()

X = df.x
Y = df.y
r1 = p.line(x=X, y=Y, line_width=2)
ds = r1.data_source

def update():
  f = open('lines.csv', 'r')
  cv = pd.read_csv(f)
  df = pd.DataFrame(cv)

  ds.data['x'] = df.x
  ds.data['y'] = df.y
  f.close()

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 50)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Nice one Luke, baffling library.